# How can I add a clickable link into this span?

Tags: html, css

please forgive if this is a dumb question, just starting to learn.

I want to make  "[SURCHARGE-FREE ATM LOCATION FINDER]" clickable to go to a website. This is the line of code:

```
            <div><span>[SURCHARGE-FREE ATM LOCATION FINDER]</span></div>
```

Using

```
<div><span><a href="https://moneypass.com/atm-locator.html">[SURCHARGE-FREE ATM LOCATION FINDER]</a></span></div>
```

did not work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `<a href="#">` will work  I suspect you were just using it incorrectly. Please post your original HTML that contains your non-working `<a href="#">` element.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This was the code I am using, but it is not working

<div><span><a href="https://moneypass.com/atm-locator.html">[SURCHARGE-FREE ATM LOCATION FINDER]</a></span></div>

Comment: Your problem is your `href=""` attribute is missing the URI scheme (`https://` or `http://`). You cannot have just a domain-name and path in `href=""`.

Comment: Thank you, Dai. To clarify, the code I am running includes the URI scheme. I don't know why it didn't appear on my comment. So, my code looks like this, yet there is no "clickable link" when I run the HTML code in my browser. Could it be because I am using Google Chrome that it is not displaying?

<div><span><a href= "https:// moneypass.com/atm-locator.html">[SURCHARGE-FREE ATM LOCATION FINDER]</a></span></div>

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div>
      <span>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
          [SURCHARGE-FREE ATM LOCATION FINDER]
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example that might help out. This [links](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) to the docs

`<div><span><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">[SURCHARGE-FREE ATM LOCATION FINDER]</a></span></div>`

Comment: This won't work because `stackoverflow.com` is not an absolute URI, so browsers will `GET http://whateverthecurrentwebsiteis.com/currentpagepath/stackoverflow.com`. You need to prefix it with either `//`, `https://`, or `http://`.

Comment: Yup that's my bad. It was just an example website, but I get the literalness